# ssh not working from PowerShell - failed to initialize w32posix wrapper

Tags: powershell, ssh

SSH is not working from PowerShell if it's not open as administrator.

If I open PowerShell and try to connect on a server over ssh I receive an error:
ssh -vvv user@host
failed to initialize w32posix wrapper

If PowerShell is open "Run as Administrator" ssh is working properly.

Comment: So what is the issue? Often code will only work As Admin.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with VS Code because is using CMD to ssh on a remote server. I install openSSH under my user and configure VS Code to use the new PATH.